# RaspberryPi 2 GPIO stopped working

Tags: gpio, pi-2, archlinux

I have RaspberryPI with Arch Linux and everything was going well, until this morning when I tried to do my usual work on it, it sounds like nothing happening at all, I have checked with pintest (I use wiringPi with C) it gives me every thing is ok, also with

```
gpio readall
```

gives me the right mode of each pin but there is no output voltage at all and also the input doesn't work.
I don't know what other information should I have to give, thanks in advance

[EDIT] this is from dmesg when plug/unplug pins

```
[  843.113721] unexport_store: invalid GPIO 54
[  843.121335] unexport_store: invalid GPIO 55
[  843.128500] unexport_store: invalid GPIO 56
[  843.135603] unexport_store: invalid GPIO 57
[  843.142607] unexport_store: invalid GPIO 58
[  843.149484] unexport_store: invalid GPIO 59
[  843.156185] unexport_store: invalid GPIO 60
[  843.162787] unexport_store: invalid GPIO 61
[  843.169344] unexport_store: invalid GPIO 62
[  900.755908] unexport_store: invalid GPIO 54
[  900.762510] unexport_store: invalid GPIO 55
[  900.769032] unexport_store: invalid GPIO 56
[  900.775299] unexport_store: invalid GPIO 57
[  900.781537] unexport_store: invalid GPIO 58
[  900.787763] unexport_store: invalid GPIO 59
[  900.793878] unexport_store: invalid GPIO 60
[  900.800008] unexport_store: invalid GPIO 61
[  900.806074] unexport_store: invalid GPIO 62
```

Also this is the result of running pigpio's gpiotest script

```
Testing...
Skipped non-user gpios: 0 1 28 29 30 31 
Tested user gpios: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22     23 24 25 26 27 
Failed user gpios: None
```

I have shutdown it and in the current boot it gives me

```
Under-voltage detected! (0x00050005)
```

here is the output of `dmesg | tail -20`

```
[   13.546068] usbcore: registered new interface driver rt2800usb
[   14.368982] 8021q: 802.1Q VLAN Support v1.8
[   14.541797] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Loading     firmware file 'rt2870.bin'
[   14.602367] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Firmware detected - version: 0.36
[   14.777248] random: crng init done
[   14.782251] random: 7 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting
[   14.952350] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   15.048969] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
[   15.059845] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   15.675877] Under-voltage detected! (0x00050005)
[   16.651969] wlan0: authenticate with 70:2e:22:79:65:d8
[   16.687697] wlan0: send auth to 70:2e:22:79:65:d8 (try 1/3)
[   16.697599] wlan0: authenticated
[   16.705767] wlan0: associate with 70:2e:22:79:65:d8 (try 1/3)
[   16.717847] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 70:2e:22:79:65:d8 (capab=0x411     status=0 aid=6)
[   16.737762] wlan0: associated
[   20.907333] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[   23.995834] Voltage normalised (0x00000000)
[   26.075861] Under-voltage detected! (0x00050005)
[   30.235820] Voltage normalised (0x00000000)
```

Comment: How did you check the output/input voltage(s)? And: what is your question?

Comment: Actually it was working properly, I have checked it by running simple blink program, the question is: Is there any other method to check/fix it, or is that occasionally happening

Comment: Your RPi is a relatively simple computer, anyway it MUST do what you ask for. Therefore, there is nothing like 'occasionally happen'. I would check all connections and wires. Do you use any of breadboards? They are bringing problems quite often. If you can provide a picture of your setup solution can be faster...

Comment: I use a PCB and everything was working properly, also I have checked the LEDs of the circuit they are working properly, also checked the wires and nothing with them.

Comment: Those GPIO don't exist so it's not surprising they give an error message.  Is everything working as expected apart from those "error" messages?

Comment: No, nothing is working, is there anyway to check the GPIO???

Comment: I thought you had?  Try pigpio's gpiotest as well.  It is slightly more thorough.

Comment: What is the Ampere rating of our 5V power supply?

Answer (score 0):

To check the GPIO try wiringPi's pintest or my pigpio's [gpiotest](https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Testing).

Both tests should be run with nothing connected to the GPIO on the expansion header.

wiringPi and pigpio are likely both pre-installed on standard Raspbian.

Comment: I have tried pintest and it gives me that everything is ok
 The main 8 GPIO pins  0: 7:  OK
                The 5 SPI pins 10:14:  OK
               The serial pins 15:16:  OK
                  The I2C pins  8: 9:  OK

Comment: I have tried it and it gives me 
Testing...
Skipped non-user gpios: 0 1 28 29 30 31 
Tested user gpios: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 
Failed user gpios: None

Comment: That shows that the GPIO are okay (they can be set high and low, the inputs works, and the pull-up, pull-downs work).  You need to explain in detail what you think isn't working and edit your question to explain and show the hardware and wiring you are using.

Comment: I have shout  it down for about 2 hours, and when I run it gives me "under-voltage detected! (0x00050005)", I will include the output of dmesg | tail in the question

Comment: That just means you need a better power supply.